# DataReader[i] vs DataReader.GetValue(i) vs DataReader.GetString(i)

Tags: .net, ado.net, datareader

Is

```
dataReader[i]
```

logically equivalent to

```
dataReader.GetValue(i)
```

Are they the same? Are they different? Is there a situation where one would be appropriate over the other?

There are [documented differently](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.aspx):

> - *Gets the column located at the specified index*
> - *Return the value of the specified field.*

But when i use them they both return the value of the field. What does it mean to "get the column"? What does it mean to "return the value of a field"?

---

**Bonus Chatter**:

When I call:

```
reader[i];
reader.GetValue(i);
reader.GetString(i);
```

i get a `String` each time

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ultimately it depends on the particular implementation of `System.Data.IDataReader` you are referring to, but let's assume you mean `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader`.

In this case, `reader[i]` and `reader.GetValue(i)` do *exactly* the same thing. In fact, `reader[i]` internally calls `reader.GetValue(i)`. (You can see this by disassembling the code using a tool like [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx).). Both these members return the value in the i-th column of the current row and will return successfully regardless of the type of the value (the return type is `object`). The documentation for both of these members is a little misleading and could be worded in a better way. You can use either of these members wherever you like, just pick the one which you feel reads better.

Whereas `reader.GetString(i)` is specifically designed to return the value contained in the i-th column of the current row as a `string`. If the value in that column is not a `string`, an `InvalidCastException` will be thrown. Use this method when you are sure that the value is a `string` and `string` is the type that you want to work with. This will make your code more concise since you won't have to perform a cast.

In your specific case, the value in the i-th column of the current row must be of type `string`, which is why the return value of all three members is identical.

If written correctly, other implementations of `System.Data.IDataReader` should behave in the same way.

Comment: There are horrible edge cases, where `GetValue` returns a `byte`, but `GetInt32` is unable to cast a byte to a Int32

Comment: It's difficult to tell (specially because the disassembled code is hard to follow) but it appears the the value in the column must already be of the desired type otherwise the InvalidCastException (which is itself a little misleading) will be thrown. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Indeed, the documentation for GetInt32 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getint32.aspx) states that "No conversions are performed; therefore, the data retrieved must already be a 32-bit signed integer." The other GetXXX methods are similarly documented.

Comment: @Ian, @Adam: That is simply related to (un)boxing; not directly related to `SqlDataReader`, `IDataReader` etc themselves. Generally, boxed values can only be unboxed to their *exact* type. For example, `object o = (byte)42; int i = (int)o;` will fail with exactly the same error, even though an unboxed `(byte)42` can happily be cast to an `int`.